# Reading the file according to some types

Tags: c, file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct products{
  char uAd;
  int uSat;
  int uAl;
  int uStk;
};


int main(){
    int line = 0;
    char chr;
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt","r");
    if(f==NULL) {
        perror("No file exist!!!");
    }
    chr = fgetc(f);
    while(chr!=EOF){
       if(chr == '\n'){
            line++;
       }
       chr = fgetc(f);
    }
    struct products U[line];
    int i= 0;
    while(!feof(f)){
        fscanf(f, "%4c %3d %3d %3d", 
            &U[i].uAd, &U[i].uSat, &U[i].uAl, &U[i].uStk);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);

    for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
      printf("%-4c %-3d %-3d %-3d\n", 
          U[j].uAd, U[j].uSat, U[j].uAl, U[j].uStk);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
PRODUCTSName   SalePice  cost  stocknumber

A                  20    15    5

B                  50    30    10

CD                 60    40    2

O                  77    35    20

EFG                3     1     100

A                  20    15    25

HJ                 150   100   8

KLMN               5     1     23

O                  77    35    12

O                  77    35    40
```

How can code read this file?

Comment: ```chr``` should be an int.  There are other problems in your code, but what exactly is the problem here? What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure to **ask a question** - we [cannot provide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/) "help". If something specific goes wrong when you try to use your existing code, it [is your responsibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [identify that problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) first, create a [mre], explain specifically the problem (What happens? What should happen instead? How is that different)? and then ask.

Comment: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: Also, the `%c` format is to read a ***single*** character, not a string of characters.

Comment: I also recommend you learn about [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and `sscan`. And *always* check what any `scanf` family function [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: You forgot to `rewind(f)`.

Comment: And try avoiding [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) (like the `10` in your output loop, at that point you *know* the number of lines you have read).

Comment: Also, once you have reached the end of the file you're stuck at the end of the file. At least until you [*rewind*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) back to the stast.

Comment: All in all I would summarize your problems as: Skipped to many classes, or chapters of your beginners books.

Comment: Don't limit the number of characters scanned with `fscanf` except to prevent string overflow. Any surplus are used by the next specifier, and if there is say `1000` for `%3d` it will all go wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "Skipped to many classes,"  hmm, perhaps somebody skipped [too many](https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2022/10/when-should-you-use-too-many-vs-to-many.html#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20modify,to%20many”%20in%20this%20instance.) English classes? ;-)

Comment: @Haris i am still struggling to read the file.. like some files are separeted with different things.. and i still don't understand the logic of fscanf and  all scanf family...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Actually it was the German language classes I skipped, not the English, but still... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not `while(!feof(f))`**

See [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong).

**`chr` too small**

`fgetc()` returns 257 different values.  Some info is lost saving as a `char`.

```
// char chr;
int chr;
```

**Iffy line count**

A file's last *line* might not end with a `'\n'`.  Instead count the beginnings of a line.

```
size_t line = 0;
int previous = '\n';
while ((chr = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
  if (previous == '\n') line++;
  previous = chr;
}
```

**Rewind**

After reading the file to count `'\n'`, the file needed to rewind before reading again for data.

```
rewind(f);
```

**Read lines**

Read a *line* of file input with `fgets()`.

**Use a larger `.uAd`**

To store 1 to 4 characters, form a *string*.

```
// char uAd;
char uAd[5];
```

**Parse with `sscanf()`**

Look for trailing junk too.

```
size_t i; 
for (i = 0; i < line; i++ ) {
  #define LINE_SIZE 100
  char buf[LINE_SIZE];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f) == NULL) {
    break;
  }
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, "%4s %3d %3d %3d %n", 
    U[i].uAd, &U[i].uSat, &U[i].uAl, &U[i].uStk, &n);
  if (n == 0 || buf[n]) {
    // Scan failed or extra junk
    break;
  }
  i++;
}

// `i` now has the record count, which might be less than `line`.
```

**Print**

Use `i` from above to limit iterations and `"%s"` to print a *string*.

---

Additional issues

- Handle potential `line == 0` before `struct products U[line];`
- Large lines counts.
- Checking of acceptable values in `struct products` members.
- Code should not continue, but exit after `perror("No file exist!!!");`
- Does the input file really contain "PRODUCTSName   SalePice  cost  stocknumber"?  If so, code needs to read and skip that line.
- If there is a blank line between, code needs to account for that in reading.

...

Comment: @Mahami If you've found what you needed in an SO "answer", it is _good form_ to "accept" the answer (it becomes marked specially) so that other readers may also find their solutions before posting duplications of similar problems.